# After opening Silverlight in VS2010 exception occurs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, exception

I am opening silverlight application in vs2010,silverlight version = 3, choosing the radio button for host the silverlight application in a new website.

Then the page loads with an exception in the designer view.

Exception is : System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please suggest how to solve this error?[image]

Comment: could u paste the full stack trace?

Comment: u want me to show the whole exception??

Comment: can you please suggest  me atleast how to solve it???

Comment: Have you tried quitting Visual Studio, deleting the project's `bin` and `obj` folders, restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding the solution?

Comment: Yes i did it , I am getting the error - the silverlight developer runtime is not installed. Please install the matching version

Comment: @LukeWoodward so what u suggest??

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are getting the error because the Silverlight 3 Developer Runtime is not installed.

Ensure you've downloaded and installed the following:

[Silverlight 3 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=d09b6ecf-9a45-4d99-b752-2a330a937bc4) 
[Silverlight 3 Developer Runtime](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=143433)

Acknowledgement: these links were taken from [this blog article by Karine Bosch](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/visual-studio-2010-and-silverlight-3/).

Comment: silver light sdk is installed as well as silverlight 4 sdk too

Comment: Have you installed the Silverlight **3** Developer Runtime?

Comment: if I am trying to install siverlight developer runtime it is saying a new version is already installed

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling all later versions of the Silverlight Developer Runtime (4 and perhaps 5 as well), installing the Silverlight 3 Developer Runtime and then reinstalling any versions you uninstalled?

Comment: Which version of Silverlight do you have installed? 4 or 5?  Try installing the Developer Runtime for that version.